# Ionic / Angular: Avoiding the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a form and I would like to display different content depending on if a client's email is available. I have a simple input with the following markup:

```
<ion-input *ngIf="client.email" readonly="true" [(ngModel)]="client.email" type="text" name="email"></ion-input>
```

But this causes an error:

> Uncaught Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'email_goes_here'.

What is the workaround to avoid this? I load `client` in my component's `ionViewWillEnter` *lifecycle hook*.

Comment: dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364880/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

Comment: see this article to understand the error [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around to this problem is to put everything inside a `setTimeout` method.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46701945/2708210) might help